# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution

Tags: variables, indexing, scalar

Currently trying to model a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, c and d are two randomly chosen particles from the system, and a and b are their respective energies. Trying to create a function that simulates 10 collisions that subtracts one energy off particle c if it is not at the ground state, then adds this to the energy of particle d. Help would be much appreciated.
[Code cell 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm52w.png)
[Code cell 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJI2Z.png)

Everything is detailed in the details of the problem.

Comment: Please post he code ans error as text, not the screenshot.